# Colored box with automatic line- and page break?

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking, boxes, mdframed, parbox

Is there a way I can get a box with a certain background color that supports automatic line breaks and automatic page breaks, i. e. automatically continues on the next page?

As of now I am using `mdframed` and `\parbox`:

```
\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=0pt, backgroundcolor=mygrey, innertopmargin=10pt, innerbottommargin=10pt]
\parbox{\textwidth}{Text inside box.}
\end{mdframed}
```

This does indeed support line break, however there is no automatic page breaking.
Is there any way I can have both?

Comment: the parbox is stopping page breaking, just use mdframed the whole point of that environment is that it allows line and page breaks

Comment: well if I use mdframed alone i do not get any line breaking at all..? any suggestions how to solve that?

Comment: with a real linewidth not 0pt you should get breaking, as I say that is the whole point of the environment. If you had supplied a real test file, not just a fragment that won't run and doesn't have enough text to linebreak, someone would probably have answered by now. `tcolorbox` is another newer package with similar (but more extensive) features,

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the inner `\parbox` which, being a box, prevents page breaks and specify a desired line breaking width to `mdframed` (the posted code sets the linewidth to 0pt which is rather odd and would prevent any sensible line breaking).